# Android Studio Upgrade Introduced Gradle Build Errors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've updated Android Studio to 0.8.11 and now when I build, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/chris/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/chris/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /Users/chris/myapps/test/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/chris/myapps/test/app/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /Users/chris/myapps/test/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /Users/chris/myapps/test/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/chris/myapps/test/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.chris.test -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/chris/myapps/test/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
>     Error Code:
>       1
>     Output:
>       /Users/chris/myapps/test/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/Icon
>       : error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.

In the Android Studio Project Panel, I don't actually see a /Users/chris/myapps/test/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/ folder. But looking at that location in Terminal/Finder does reveal a 0-byte file named "Icon?".

Any ideas as to what's causing this?

Comment: did you try clicking `Build -> Clean Project`, `intermediates` folder is temp so try removing that file, see if it repeats.

Comment: @ashoke, for some reason, Clean Project results in the same error.

Comment: Do you have a file named like that in your resources? If so, you'll need to change it. I think the error isn't related to the 0.8.11 upgrade.